# SQLException(Invalid column index) - no result appear in the page

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

I'm trying to apply search (select statement) based  in a specific fields  in my DB but I have this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index.
```

```
public List<SearchResultDto> search(SearchDto searchDto) {
    Connection connection = null;

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet searchResultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT I_ID, I_NO, I_TITLE, I_DESCRIPTION, I_CREATED_DATE, STATUS.S_DESCRIPTION, APPL_USER.U_NAME FROM IDEA IDEA, STATUS STATUS, APPL_USER APPL_USER WHERE IDEA.I_STATUS_CODE = STATUS.S_CODE AND IDEA.I_CREATED_USER_ID = APPL_USER.U_SEQ AND IDEA.I_NO = ? OR IDEA.I_TITLE LIKE '%?%' OR TRUNC(IDEA.I_CREATED_DATE)= ?  OR STATUS.S_CODE = ? ");



        // Assign first value to first parameter
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, searchDto.getIdeaNo());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, searchDto.getIdeaTitle());
        preparedStatement.setDate(3, searchDto.getCreatedDate() == null ? null
                : new java.sql.Date(searchDto.getCreatedDate().getTime()));
        preparedStatement.setObject(4, searchDto.getIdeaStatus());

        searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        return search(searchResultSet);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (searchResultSet != null) {
                searchResultSet.close();
            }

            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

private List<SearchResultDto> search(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<SearchResultDto> result = new ArrayList<SearchResultDto>();

SearchResultDto searchResultDto = null;

    while (searchResultSet.next()) {
        ideaSearchResultDto = new SearchResultDto();

        searchResultDto.setIdeaId(searchResultSet.getLong(1));
        searchResultDto.setIdeaNo(searchResultSet.getLong(2));
        searchResultDto.setTitle(searchResultSet.getString(3));
        searchResultDto.setDescription(searchResultSet.getString(4));
        searchResultDto.setCreatedDate(searchResultSet.getDate(5));
        searchResultDto.setStatusDescription(searchResultSet.getString(6));
        searchResultDto.setIdeaCreator(searchResultSet.getString(7));

        result.add(searchResultDto);

    }

    return result;
}
```

this is my jsf file:

```
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="70px"><h:outputText value="No"></h:outputText>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="5px"> </td>
                                                    <td><h:inputText

                                                            maxlength="10" style="width:150px"
                                                            value="#{searchBean.searchDto.no}"></h:inputText>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="50px"> </td>
                                                    <td width="70px"><h:outputText value="status"></h:outputText>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="5px"> </td>
                                                    <td><h:selectOneMenu
                                                            value="#{searchBean.searchDto.status}"
                                                            style="width:150px">
                                                            <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.statuses}" />
                                                        </h:selectOneMenu></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="70px"><h:outputText value="Title"></h:outputText>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="5px"> </td>
                                                    <td><h:inputText maxlength="100"
                                                            value="#{searchsBean.searchDto.Title}"
                                                            style="width:150px"></h:inputText></td>
                                                    <td width="50px"> </td>
                                                    <td width="70px"><h:outputText value="created Date"></h:outputText>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="5px"> </td>
                                                    <td><rich:calendar
                                                            value="#{searchBean.searchDto.createdDate}"
                                                            datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" inputStyle="width:150px"></rich:calendar>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </rich:panel></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="center">
                <table>
                    <tr>

                        <td width="3px"><h:commandButton image="search.png"
                                actionListener="#{searchBean.doSearch}"></h:commandButton>
                        <td width="3px"><h:commandButton image="clean.png"
                                actionListener="#{searchBean.doClear}"></h:commandButton>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>





        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><rich:datascroller renderIfSinglePage="false" align="center" for="ideasTable"
                                id="ideasTableScroller" /> 
                                <rich:dataTable
                                rendered="#{searchBean.showResultsTable}" rows="15"
                                rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
                                value="#{searchIBean.result}" var="record"
                                id="ideasTable">
                                <rich:column width="80px" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="No"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{record.no}"></h:outputText>
                                </rich:column>
                                <rich:column width="250px" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="title"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{record.title}"></h:outputText>
                                </rich:column>
                                <rich:column width="90px" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="description"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{record.description}"></h:outputText>
                                </rich:column>
                                <rich:column width="90px" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="created Date"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{record.createdDate}"></h:outputText>
                                </rich:column>
                                <rich:column width="80px" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="status"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{record.statusDescription}"></h:outputText>
                                </rich:column>
                                <rich:column width="70px" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="creator"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{record.creator}"></h:outputText>
                                </rich:column>

                                <rich:column width="115px" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><h:commandLink
                                                    action="#{searchBean.goDetails}" value="Details">
                                                    <f:param name="ideaId" value="#{record.id}"></f:param>
                                                </h:commandLink></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><h:commandLink
                                                    action="#{searchBean.goAttachments}"
                                                    value="Attachments">
                                                    <f:param name="ideaId" value="#{record.id}"></f:param>
                                                </h:commandLink></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </rich:column> 
                            </rich:dataTable></td>
                    </tr>
```

I have this method in the bean:

```
public void doSearch(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

    result = delegate.search(searchDto);

    if (result == null || result.size() == 0) {
        addInformationMessage("no data");
    }
}


public String goDetails() {
    long ideaId = Long.parseLong(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("ideaId"));

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("ideaId", 
        ideaId);

    return "goIdeaDetails";
}
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>Search</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/Search</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>goIdeaDetails</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/IdeaDetails</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

may be the exception come from the action of the Commend Link ?

Comment: `LIKE '%?%'` you should add the `%` to the value that you are setting with e.g. setString (2, "%test%");`

Comment: Do you understand the error Message? You ask for a column not present.

Comment: You missed the first line of java code from code formatting, and you should  reduce the indentation of your JSP code. You might also consider writing a [mcve] of the JSP file.

Comment: thank you for your replay, actually the exception is Invalid column index but when i did not enter any value the exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: did i use TRUNC operator in right way ?

Comment: You used the LIKE operator in the wrong way. As @ScaryWombat sayd, correct " LIKE '%?%' " to " LIKE ? " and preparedStatement.setString(2, "%"+ideaTitle+"%");  Please provide and study StackTraces a with exceptions,. NullPointerException can happen everywhere. What exact datatype do serchResultDTO.ideaId and .ideaNo have? If they are primitives, assigning NULL potentially received from ResultSet will result in NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `IDEA.I_TITLE LIKE '%?%'`. You should not put any quotes across wild card character.

You should tweak your query to : `IDEA.I_TITLE LIKE ?`

and change your parameter to

```
preparedStatement.setString(2, "%"+searchDto.getIdeaTitle()+"%");
```

Comment: _"You should tweak your query to : `IDEA.I_TITLE LIKE %?%`"_ this doesn't make sense, as that will be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `'%?%'` is a string literal, the `?` in that literal is just a question mark in text, not a parameter marker. So instead of 4 parameters, your query only has 3 parameters.

Instead you need to change this to either `like '%' + ? + '%'` (or `like '%' || ? || '%'` for standard SQL), or you need to use `like ?` and change your `setString` call to include the wildcards.

Comment: Thank you all, i fix the error now but I have new exception which is : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: This one : javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /SearchIdeas.jsp(148,24) '#{searchIdeasBean.doSearch}' java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:118)

Comment: @wadhaalketbi That provides no relevant information to me and I don't think it is directly related to your original question, consider posting a **new** question, and make sure to include the **full* stacktrace in that question.

Comment: This is what happened with me after i fix the first exception, I post the Jsp and bean methods up

Comment: @wadhaalketbi And likely that is just another problem that has surfaced after you fixed the initial problem. Post a **new** question, don't expand the scope of an existing question or change its meaning. Asking a new question will have more chance of getting an answer for that new problem.